# Error: Element type "div" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>"

Tags: visualforce, html

> Error: Element type "div" must be followed by either attribute
>   specifications, ">" or "/>".

```
<apex:page standardController="ADSS_Platform_Account__c" showHeader="false" standardStylesheets="false">   
    <div style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 12px;color: #ffffff;" "height: 100%" class="bodyDiv"  onclick="resizeFrame();">  
        <c:IBHierarchyTree currentId="{!ADSS_Platform_Account__c.id}"/>   
    </div>  
</apex:page>
```

I removed left angular brackets because i was not able to post my code.

Comment: Please correct the formatting of your code.

Comment: @vamsi 
how to add VF page code, please suggest so that next time I will add the formatted code

Comment: Just add 4 spaces before each line. See the StackExchange manual and FAQ.

Comment: you need to use the formatting toolbar options in the editor where you paste your code. select your code and click the { } toolbar button to format the code

Comment: cool, I got it now!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

height: 100% falls under style-size attribute string , 
thus

**"** font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 12px;color: #ffffff; **"**
**and**
 **"** height: 100% **"**
should be written as same string as ,

style=**"** font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 12px;color: #ffffff;height: 100% **"**

Please hit like , if you find the information relevant.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!!
am not able to set color as black for this as mentioned in style it is showing blue !!

Comment: Answer - use color: #000000  /  color:black

Explaination -
The color combination varies from #000000 (BLACK) to #FFFFFF (WHITE).
So, you should use #000000 to have black color font or you can simply write black also.
Thus , just change the style attribute from
 style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 12px;color: #ffffff;height: 100%"
to
div style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 12px;color: #000000;height: 100%"

or

div style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 12px;color: black;height: 100%"

Answer (score 5):

```
div style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 12px;color: #ffffff;" "height: 100%" class="bodyDiv" onclick="resizeFrame();">
```

Change this line into

```
div style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 12px;color: #ffffff;height: 100%" class="bodyDiv" onclick="resizeFrame();">
```

Comment: Thank you Tushar,  but I am not sure what is the change? 
and one doubt if you don't mind, I am not able to set color as black for this as mentioned in style